# PCB Integrated Chip Question

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, ground, eaglecad

Hi I am building a PCB using eagle and its the first time I am using an IC. Two questions arose.

1. Do I need to connect the IC chip's ground, because eagle did not do it?
2. Do I need to make sure all of the ground orphans are connected?

Thank you guys in advanced!

[image: IC picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what this means is that the combination of the isolate and width settings on your polygon are resulting in the plane not being allowed to extend to the pins.

I can only presume that you have hidden the 'unrouted' layer, or hidden airwires for that net, hence the pins aren't showing up as connected. If you type the command `ratsnest gnd` (where gnd is the name of the net that your ground plane is part of), this should restore visibility of the airwires.

What I usually do in this scenario (in fact I do it anyway even if the plane could have reached) is run wires out from the pin towards where the plane is - they don't have to actually go anywhere else, just a line straight out from the pin. This means that they will always become connected and you never run into the issue.

---

As a side note, just as a bit of friendly advice, I would always try to make sure your wires come out from the pins of the chip in the same direction as the pin - for that chip it would be either vertically or horizontally (0 or 90 degrees). While in part this is to make the design look neater, it also means the wires don't get closer than necessary to the adjacent pins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must connect all the IC's ground (and power) pins as required.

With some (most?) CAD systems there can be a problem wth "hidden" nets - power and ground pins often do not appear on the schematic, and are assumed to automagically connect to like-named nets.

I once experienced a missing ground problem with Protel due to hidden pins - the ground pins on a microcontroller were called "Vdd" (or maybe Vss - I can't remember which is equivalent to Gnd) and my ground net was logically called "Gnd", as I was using some bipolar TTL parts - the result was that the processor's "ground" pins were not connected to the rest of the circuit - result was no power on the processor - no work!!

Answer (score 0):

If your part has multiple GND pins, how were they labeled (eg. GND@1, GND@2, etc.)? Are they all connected to GND in the schematic? As others have mentioned, check the isolate and wire size for the polygon pours. Also, it is good layout style to make your traces come out of the package 90 degrees (considering the package outline on tPlace to be 0 degrees).